# I'm working on Micheal Hartls Rail Tutorial book I used the same code but got different result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, reset

I'm working on Micheal Hartls Rail Tutorial book on chapter 12.3 I used the same code as written on the book but the code renders the home page instead of the edit form.

### edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Reset password</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_with(model: @user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]),
                  local: true) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb

  before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
 
  def edit
  end

  private

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

 [![ with these code and pasting the link on my browser, I should get this form but instead I got the home page][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kikkF.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly I do not have enough SO reputation to write a comment, I'll use answer form instead.

```
    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

Portion of your code validates 1. User presence, 2. User activation, 3. User's reset token written into database to confirm it's the valid password reset request.
If any of these validations fail - your controller is redirecting the request to root_url.

My suggestion would be to doublecheck if your user has activated account, that would mean clicking the activation link before trying to reset the user's password.

Hope that helps, thanks!